# When I use Scrapy to grab next_url, the response shows the right url but the response body shows another

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to grab the `next_url`, however I got a different response than I did previously which makes me confused. 
I put my code below:

```
import scrapy
class Books2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'books2'
   start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

   def parse(self, response):
    print(response)
    for book in response.css('article.product_pod'):
        name = book.xpath('./h3/a/@title').extract_first()
        price = response.css('p.price_color::text').extract_first()
        yield{
            'name':name,
            'price':price
        }

    next_url = response.css('ul.pager li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    print(next_url)
    print(self.counters)
    if next_url:
        next_url = response.urljoin(next_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

When I run the spider on company wifi, I could get `next_url` but the response seemed a little weird. I put it below.

```
response = {HtmlResponse} <200 http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html>
     body = {bytes: 1007} b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<script language="javascript">setTimeout("location.replace(location.href.split(\\"#\\")[0])",2000);</script>\r\n<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1.1.1.2:89/cookie/flash.js"></script>\r\n<script language="javascript">setURL("
```

**The url is correct, but the body seems to be redirected to 1.1.1.2:89, and can not be select the xpath and css correctly. Why?**

What differences I found are below:

1. When I use my home wifi, it could run ok
2. When I switch to my phone hotspot, it could run ok

Comment: If it only happens in your company WiFi, you should ask your company. I’m guessing the same happens if you use `curl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , As I learnt from our company ,it may be something setting which I don't know and I can't figure out in my project. What i think is how to jump over this limits